# Trying to save current date permentently

Tags: java

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdf.format(now);
```

I am trying to display the current date permanently.

I have tried:

```
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdf.format(now);
```

but it is returning an error

Comment: i guess you mean: "I am trying to display the current date CONTINOUSLY." right?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I can't see any issue with this.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not posted your error, and looking at your code which looks fine, the best guess is you are getting the following error:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for Date() 
Date now = new Date();
constructor Date.Date(long) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Date.Date(int,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
```

Which happens when you use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`, since `SimpleDateFormat.format()` accepts parameter of type `java.util.Date` .

Change your import statement to `import java.util.Date`

Or worst case, you have not added any imports so add the following:

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```